# Mono Crash Exception : VAR 3 (TOutput) cannot be expanded in this context with 3 instantiations

Tags: .net, crash, mono, debian

I am having this issue when I am trying to run a windows program (runs fine on windows) that uses DOTNET 4.6.1.
I have installed the latest version of mono and the program starts just fine but then crashes with the following error.

Can someone help please??????

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9DDj.png)

Comment: You can only help yourself in this case, https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/application-portability/#developing-on-windows-running-on-unix Besides, since anyway you need to migrate the code base, you should really consider migrating to .NET Core (aka .NET 6) at this moment.

Comment: Hi @LexLi, thanks for jumping in. I'm on Debian on a raspberry pi. Is there any ways for me to get DotNet 4.6 on there. I have wine and winetricks installed but it crashes as well earlier than with mono, not even starting the application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.